# Deep learning for pattern recognition for clothes and shoes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, object-recognition

I am newbie in deep learning, so not sure about the ability of deep learning. I am wondering if it is possible to use DL for pattern recognition. More specific, given many images containing different people wearing the same clothes or shoes. Can we tell it out that certain patterns in these images are the same, i.e. wearing the same clothes or shoes?

If yes, what is the pipeline to do it? From the beginning of data preparation to the end of classification/prediction? Any reference papers or blogs recommended? Thanks in advance!

Here are some examples I found online for better illustration:

[enter link description here](http://www.papermag.com/uploaded_images/cine_wintourjacobs-Co%CC%81pia.jpg)

[enter link description here](http://images.trendnstylez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Italian-fashion-trends-prada-ss-2013.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could gather from your problem statement, I believe if you require some general similarity you should go for an unsupervised clustering algorithm. It will create groups for your data set based on hidden similarities but you will have to label the clusters yourself which might not be very useful in your case.

Another approach could be to manually label your images with categories of interest for instance same background, same shoes, same clothes etc and train a multi class convolutional neural network.

Neural network would probably give you better results or you can even use the deep feather the neural net learned to extract features from your data and use a clustering algorithm on the extracted features.

This is an interesting time to be learning about deep learning. [These](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials) tutorials might help you.
Let me know if I can help further.